# Notebook authoring and publishing tool?

Tags: python

I often find myself using jupyter notebooks for "back of the envelope" calculations, which are sometimes interesting enough (to me) that I want to publish them.

- I wish there were a notebook **authoring** tool which felt more like a modern text editor (e.g. sublime)
- I wish there were a notebook **publishing** tool which resulted in beautiful blog posts (e.g. medium)

Tools I'm aware of:

- Jupyter
- nbviewer (https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/)
- Jupyter Book
- Colab
- Observable
- Streamlit

I don't think any of these meet my use case very well, for reasons specific to each one. Are there others I should take a look at?